# golang append() evaluated but not used

Tags: arrays, go, var

```
func main(){
     var array [10]int
     sliceA := array[0:5]
     append(sliceA, 4)
     fmt.Println(sliceA)
}
```

> Error : append(sliceA, 4) evaluated but not used

I don't Know why? The slice append operation is not run...

Comment: Because `append` returns result, and you don't use it.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Refer: [Appending to and copying slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)

In Go, arguments are passed by value.

Typical `append` usage is:

```
a = append(a, x)
```

You need to write:

```
func main(){
    var array [10]int
    sliceA := array[0:5]
    // append(sliceA, 4)  // discard
    sliceA = append(sliceA, 4)  // keep
    fmt.Println(sliceA)
}
```

**Output**:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 4]
```

Comment: Would be nice to know why a return value is necessary. I'm assuming it's because you could do `sliceB := append(sliceA, 4)` without changing sliceA. In contrast, delete() modifies in place https://stackoverflow.com/a/71691201/722796

Answer (score 15):

```golang
sliceA = append(sliceA, 4)
```

`append()`  returns a slice containing one or more new values.
Note that we need to accept a return value from append as we may get a new slice value.

Answer (score 4):

you may try this:

```
sliceA = append(sliceA, 4)
```

built-in function `append([]type, ...type)` returns an array/slice of type, which should be assigned to the value you wanted, while the input array/slice is just a source. Simply, `outputSlice = append(sourceSlice, appendedValue)`

Answer (score 2):

Per the Go docs:

> The resulting value of append is a slice containing all the elements of the original slice plus the provided values.

So the return value of 'append', will contain your original slice with the appended portion.

Answer (score 1):

The key to understand is that slice is just a "view" of the underling array.
You pass that view to the append function **by value**, the underling array gets modified, at the end the return value of append function gives you the different view of the underling array. i.e. the slice has more items in it

```
your code
sliceA := array[0:5]  // sliceA is pointing to [0,5)
append(sliceA, 4) // sliceA is still the original view [0,5) until you do the following

sliceA = append(sliceA, 4)
```

reference: https://blog.golang.org/slices