# Delete known element from slice in Go

Tags: go, slice

I am trying to use the slices package to delete a `chan []byte` from a slice of them.
But I have a known value that I want to remove instead of using the position like it shows here [How to delete an element from a Slice in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334119/how-to-delete-an-element-from-a-slice-in-golang).

```
import "golang.org/x/exp/slices"

var receiverChannels []chan []byte

channel := make(chan []byte)
receiverChannels = append(receiverChannels, channel)

receiverChannels = slices.Delete(receiverChannels, channel)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go 1.18 solution with type parameters:

```
func Delete[T comparable](collection []T, el T) []T {
    idx := Find(collection, el)
    if idx > -1 {
        return slices.Delete(collection, idx, idx+1)
    }
    return collection
}

func Find[T comparable](collection []T, el T) int {
    for i := range collection {
        if collection[i] == el {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the ordering of the slice is not important, you can use a map instead:

```
var receiverChannels = make(map[chan []byte]struct{})

channel:=make(chan []byte)
receiverChannels[channel]=struct{}{}
delete(receiverChannels,channel)
```

Otherwise, you need a `find` helper function:

```
func find(channels []chan []byte, ch chan []byte) int {
   for i:=range channels {
     if channels[i]==ch {
        return i
     }
   }
  return -1
}
```

Or a generic `find`:

```
func find[T comparable](slice []T, item T) int {
    for i := range slice {
        if slice[i] == item {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

If you need to keep a slice but ordering is not important, you can simply move the last element and truncate the slice:

```
i:=find(receiverChannels, channel)
if i!=-1 {
  if i<len(receiverChannels)-1 {
    receiverChannels[i]=receiverChannels[len(receiverChannels)-1]
  }
  receiverChannels=receiverChannels[:len(receiverChannels)-1]
}
```

Last, if ordering is important:

```
i:=find(receiverChannels, channel)
if i!=-1 {
   receiverChannels=append(receiverChannels[:i], receiverChannels[i+1:]...)
   receiverChannels=receiverChannels[:len(receiverChannels)-1]
}
```