# What is the difference in time complexity when passing a string versus a pointer to the string as parameter to a function?

Tags: string, go, pointers, pass-by-value

Let us say I have a string s.

```
 s := "helloworld"
```

Now, my question is, if s has 'n' bytes, what is the time complexity with respect to 'n' if I pass s to a function versus if I pass &s to a function and then access the ith byte of the string.

If it takes O(1) time when I pass &s to a function and access the ith byte of the string, then will it take O(n) time when I pass s to a function and then access the ith byte of the string (because the whole string will be copied)?

I tried this and found that copying a string does indeed change the pointer to it. Would appreciate more clarity on this.

```
func main() {
    str := "helloworld"
    fmt.Println("string pointer 1:", &str)
    printStringPointer(str)
}

func printStringPointer(s string) {
    fmt.Println("string pointer 2:", &s)
}
```

Output:

```
string pointer 1: 0xc000010200
string pointer 2: 0xc000010210
```

Comment: Strings are already pointer-like values. Using `*string` is unnecessary and is just worse in performance. See [Garbage collection and correct usage of pointers in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959783/garbage-collection-and-correct-usage-of-pointers-in-go/51983331#51983331).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings in go are similar to slices, they are just a thin descriptor containing a pointer to the underlying data and a length.

You can see this in the [reflect.StringHeader](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StringHeader) type:

```
type StringHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
}
```

When passing a string to a function, the header is copied, but the underlying data is not. We can change your example to print the value of `Data`, showing that it points to the same address in memory: [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/vIKs30KWte5):

```
func main() {
    str := "helloworld"
    fmt.Println("string pointer 1: ", &str)
    fmt.Println("string Data 1:    ", (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&str)).Data)
    printStringPointer(str)
}

func printStringPointer(s string) {
    fmt.Println("string pointer 2: ", &s)
    fmt.Println("string Data 2:    ", (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)).Data)
}
```

Output:

```
string pointer 1:  0xc000010200
string Data 1:     4970654
string pointer 2:  0xc000010210
string Data 2:     4970654
```

Passing a string is **constant time** (copying the header), **the underlying data is not copied**.