# Truncate slice in place

Tags: go, slice

Given a slice (not a pointer to a slice!) is there any way to truncate it in place?

The naive implementation doesn't work, because of scope:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func truncate(s []int, to int) []int{
    s = s[:to] # <- has no effect outside this function
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    s1 := truncate(s, 3)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", s1)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", s)
}
```

prints

```
[0 1 2]
[0 1 2 3 4] # <- can we get [0 1 2] here?
```

Is there any way to modify the length or capacity of an existing slice, or are they immutable?

---

**ETA:** I thought this was obvious enough, but apparently not: when I ask whether it's possible to do this *in place*, I mean *without reassigning* `s`.

Comment: No. The slice length and capacity are not accessible parameters. The slice operations (e.g. `s[:to]`) return a new slice of the same underlying array.

Comment: @Adrian If you can link to an authoritative reference and make that an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: _"Given a slice"_ – given how? You receive it as a function parameter? That value is a copy of the original slice, and it is a different value with no "connection" to the original. So you're already at a lost cause. See [Remove from slice inplace in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56394632/remove-from-slice-inplace-in-golang/56394697#56394697); and [Are golang slices pass by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993797/1705598); and also [slice vs map to be used in parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47590531/1705598).

Comment: See the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions

Comment: An authoritative reference saying you *can't* do that? I don't think there is one; the spec doesn't enumerate the things you can't do, only the things you can.

Comment: Response to ETA: The only way to change a value in Go is to assign to the value.  Function `truncate` cannot change variable `s` in `main` because `truncate` does not have access to that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done, because [slices are passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993797/27358).

Note that as of April 2013, the Go language specification [no longer refers to slices, maps, and channels as "reference types"](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/b34f0551387fcf043d65cd7d96a0214956578f94). (The behavior didn't change, just the language used to describe it.)

It can't be done with arrays either, because [an array's length is part of its type](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6).

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://play.golang.org/p/_Z8HjfwAoAC) is the way to go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    s = truncate(s, 3)
    fmt.Println(s) // [0 1 2]
}
func truncate(s []int, to int) []int {
    return s[:to]
}
```

Slice is like a window to an underlying array.

---

[The other way using pointer to the slice](https://play.golang.org/p/4kzxg81jEVj):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    truncate(&s, 3)
    fmt.Println(s) // [0 1 2]
}

func truncate(s *[]int, to int) {
    *s = (*s)[:to]
}
```

Comment: If you read the question more carefully, this is exactly what I'm not trying to do. There's a reason why the example has the actual reslice inside the `truncate()` function.

Comment: There is no other way. slice is just a struct containing `len`, `cap`, and a pointer to the underlying array. you may use a pointer to the slice and re-slice it inside the function or this is the only way to go.