# best way to remove element from slice

Tags: go, memory-leaks, slice

I am trying to remove an element from a slice and I am wondering if this way will cause any memory leak in the application.

```
func RemoveElementInSlice(list []int32, idx int) []int32 {
    list[idx] = list[len(list)-1]
    list = list[:len(list)-1]
    return list
}
```

Here list is the slice from which I want to remove the element at index idx.
If this might cause a memory leak what is the best & safe way to do it?

Comment: See related: [Does go garbage collect parts of slices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432658/does-go-garbage-collect-parts-of-slices/28432812#28432812)

Answer (score 2):

As explained in "[Kind-of Memory Leaking Caused by Subslices](https://go101.org/article/memory-leaking.html#subslice)":

> Similarly to substrings, subslices may also cause kind-of memory leaking.
>
> In the following code, after the `g` function is called, most memory occupied by the memory block hosting the elements of `s1` will be lost (if no more values reference the memory block).
>
> ```golang
> var s0 []int
>
> func g(s1 []int) {
>   // Assume the length of s1 is much larger than 30.
>   s0 = s1[len(s1)-30:]
> }
> ```
>
> If we want to avoid the kind-of memory leaking, we must duplicate the 30 elements for `s0`, so that the aliveness of `s0` will not prevent the memory block hosting the elements of `s1` from being collected.
>
> ```golang
> func g(s1 []int) {
>   s0 = make([]int, 30)
>   copy(s0, s1[len(s1)-30:])
>   // Now, the memory block hosting the elements
>   // of s1 can be collected if no other values
>   // are referencing the memory block.
> }
> ```

````
---

But you can investigate that with pprof, as illustrated in "[Golang slice memory leak collection][2]"

```go
//Add pprof package in import
_ "net/http/pprof"
````

Then:

```
go tool pprof http://127.0.0.1:9999/debug/pprof/heap
```

---

See also [icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55046506/6309).

Comment: This is the type of memory leak reminiscent of item 7 in Josh Bloch's _Effective Java_ (3rd edition).